# Proxy setting for iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, ios4

i am new to iphone app development.i am trying to connect facebook using the facebook api's using iphone and running on iphone simulator where i have to do some proxy settings for running internet.So any of you please tell me how to make proxy settings to run internet via iphone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

if you define a proxy setting for your network connection it should work....this works for me anyway

Comment: I do have my network proxy settings defined but still its not working for me.....any other way .....